# Can I play movie files on PS4?

Tags: ps4

I would regularly use my PS3 to play movie files of various types via USB storage device, mainly .mp4 or .avi files. I would like to be able to do the same with my PS4 but I can't find any way to access any of the files on the USB stick when I plug it in to the console.

It is possible to play these movie files on the PS4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sony has launched the Media Player application at this years E3 and it is available to download directly from your XMB (cross media bar) now.

[image: Screen grab of media player app]

The following file types are supported:

***Video***

- **MKV** Visual: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level4.2
  Audio: MP3, AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
- **AVI**
  Visual: MPEG4 ASP, H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level4.2
  Audio: MP3, AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
- **MP4**
  Visual: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level4.2
  Audio: AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
- **MPEG-2** TS Visual: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level4.2, MPEG2 Visual
  Audio: MP2 (MPEG2 Audio Layer 2), AAC LC, AC-3(Dolby Digital)
  AVCHD: (.m2ts, .mts)

***Image***

- **JPEG** (based on DCF 2.0/Exif 2.21)
- **BMP**
- **PNG**

***Music***

- **MP3**
- **AAC** (M4A)

[Source: Official Playstation blog](http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2015/06/16/media-player-launches-on-ps4-today/)

Answer (score 0):

You can play them off a flash drive if you put them in a folder named, "MUSIC" in the root directory. I am unsure if it is capitalized or not but mine always is.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Tyrel! Make sure when you answer a question that you include more details, unless there isn't a much to add.